# Flatten array of objects having arrays nested within their properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

Currently I have an array that contains my clothing (fictitious data):

```
myClothes = [
    {
        type: 'shirts',
        pieces: [
            {
                brand: 'patagonia',
                quantity: 6,
            },
            {
                brand: 'hugo boss',
                quantity: 3,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'trousers',
        pieces: [
            {
                brand: 'jack & jones',
                quantity: 2,
            },
            {
                brand: 'zara',
                quantity: 4,
            },
            {
                brand: 'versace',
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        type: 'socks',
        pieces: [
            {
                brand: 'no-name',
                quantity: 12,
            },
        ],
    },  
];
```

As you see, the array contains objects (shirts, trousers, socks), that seperate the clothing by their type. Now, what can I do with javascript to make a new array of that which looks like this below here?
So where just all pieces are unseperated from shirts/trousers/socks, and it should just show how much articles I have of the brand.

```
allPiecesUnseperated = [
    {
        brand: 'patagonia',
        quantity: 6,
    },
    {
        brand: 'hugo boss',
        quantity: 3,
    },
    {
        brand: 'jack & jones',
        quantity: 2,
    },
    {
        brand: 'zara',
        quantity: 4,
    },
    {
        brand: 'versace',
        quantity: 1,
    },  
    {
        brand: 'no-name',
        quantity: 12,
    },          
];
```

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks sir. Yes, in this one case, the flattening was totally what I wanted. But my fictitious data example was not the best, maybe a little misleading. But anyways I really appreciate your response to my thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const clothes = [{
    type: 'shirts',
    pieces: [{
        brand: 'patagonia',
        quantity: 6,
      },
      {
        brand: 'hugo boss',
        quantity: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'trousers',
    pieces: [{
        brand: 'jack & jones',
        quantity: 2,
      },
      {
        brand: 'zara',
        quantity: 4,
      },
      {
        brand: 'versace',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: 'socks',
    pieces: [{
      brand: 'no-name',
      quantity: 12,
    }, ],
  },
];

const result = clothes.map(({
  pieces
}) => pieces).reduce((acc, arr) => [...acc, ...arr], []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.flatMap()` function

```js
const myClothes = [
    {
        type: 'shirts',
        pieces: [
            { brand: 'patagonia', quantity: 6 },
            { brand: 'hugo boss', quantity: 3 }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'trousers',
        pieces: [
            { brand: 'jack & jones', quantity: 2 },
            { brand: 'zara', quantity: 4, },
            { brand: 'versace', quantity: 1 }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 'socks',
        pieces: [
            { brand: 'no-name', quantity: 12 },
        ]
    }  
];

const output = myClothes.flatMap(o => o.pieces);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient (since concat does create a new array everytime it is invoked) or the most elegant solution, but should get the job done.

```
var all = []
myClothes.forEach((item) => {
    all = all.concat(item.pieces)
})
```